# Enums in Constructors in C++

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, enumerator

I am very new to Constructors and OOP in C++ and I encountered the following problem.
I try to make the following class, but apparently something is wrong with the enumerators.
Also I was wondering if I could somehow set EUR to be the default option.

```
class Amount
{
    // Todo 6.2
    // Implement class Amount
protected: 
    float Netto_;
    float Brutto_;
    enum tax_ { tax1 , tax2};
    enum Currency_ { EUR, USD }; 
    const float eur_to_usd = 1.13;
    const float usd_to_eur = 0.89;
    std::string Description_;

public:
    Amount(std::string Description , float Brutto, Currency_ Currency, tax_ taxtype) : Brutto_{Brutto} , Description_{Description}, Currency_{Currency}, tax_{taxtype} {} 

};
```

I am getting the following error:

```
"Currency_" is not a nonstatic data member or base class of class "Amount"
```

Thank you!

Comment: enum does not declare a field. it should be outside the class declaration.Then within the class you can use Currency as a type

Comment: What is unclear about the error message? `Currency_` is a type. Not a member, as `Netto_`, for example. Such error isn't limited to `enum`s either, but you would get it, if it were a `class`, as well.

Comment: You declared `enum` types, but no members of those types

Comment: @Necklondon There's nothing wrong with defining a enum inside of a class.

Comment: @Necklondon "_it should be outside the class declaration.Then within the class you can use Currency as a type_" It is perfectly valid to define a type within a type. There's nothing different in creating a member of type, that is defined outside of the `class`, from creating a member of type, that is defined inside a class.

Comment: As mentioned above, you have to define a member variable Currency of the type Currency_, but then the enum defintion should be public.

Comment: @stefan.gal no need for member variables to use public types

Comment: It's annoying to pass in the `Currency` parameter if you can't see the `Currency_`  type. Only this class or derived classes would be able to construct without playing silly games.

Comment: Unrelated, `eur_to_usd` and `usd_to_eur` should probably be `static` members

Comment: Unrelated: members are initialized in the order they are defined regardless of the order they are placed in the member initializer list. Doesn't matter here, but it's a good thing to remember if you have members that count on other members for initializing.

Comment: A consistent naming scheme would avoid such errors. Don't declare types with underscore at the end. Have all types upper camel case (pascal case), all members (apart perhaps from constants) (lower) camel case. You'll quickly get used to that, and you'll start avoiding errors like these just as quickly.

Comment: Off-topic: float (or double) are not really suitable to represent currencies. Be aware that not even most simple 0.1 can be represented exactly, as it is periodic in binary. I rather recommend using fixed comma arithmetics (i. e. representing the values in cent, 10th of or 100th of according to your needs).

Answer (score 5):

This line:

```
enum Currency_ { EUR, USD };
```

is not declaring a member variable, it is declaring a type.  Since there's no variable, you cannot initialize the variable.  You need to break it into two lines:

```
enum Currency_ { EUR, USD };
Currency_ Currency_val;
```

Comment: You can leave it one line (`enum Currency_t { EUR, USD } Currency_;`).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm absolutely correct.  I would still keep the enum declaration and variable declaration separated just for clarity.

Comment: It compiles, but such type-and-variable declarations all in one are actively discouraged for lack of readability.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare a variable of the type Currency_ and make the enum definition public in order to to use it in the constructor. (and the same for tex_)

```
class Amount
{
public: 
    enum Currency_ { EUR, USD }; 
protected:
    Currency_ Currency;
    ...
};

void test() {
    Amount amount("description", 2.0, Amount::USD, Amount::tax1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To declare a new enum *type*, you should do this:

```
enum MyEnumType {A, B, C};
```

Now you can declare instances of MyEnumType:

```
MyEnumType variable;
```

You can create the enum type inside a class, and you do.  You never actually created an instance of that type, however.

You are confusing a type with a variable.  You also have mixed capitalization for your names, which might contribute to your misunderstanding.  Capitalization should not be random, but imply meaning.  Often, *types* start with uppercase letters, *member variables* start with lowercase letters (and often end with a trailing _).  Whatever actual code style you choose, **be consistent**.  Don't declare some enums with uppercase enumerator names and other enums with lowercase enumerators, etc.  Also, you should not mix constants,  types, and variable declarations, but physically separate them into segments within your class.  That can also help make it clearer what needs initialization and what does not.

Here's a minor rearrangement of  your code, and fixing capitalization, and separation of type declarations and variable declarations:

```
#include <string>

class Amount
{
    // types (uppercase letter)
    enum Tax { TAX1, TAX2};
    enum Currency { EUR, USD }; 

    // variables (needing initialization.  All have trailing '_', not the types)
    std::string description_;
    float brutto_;
    float netto_;
    Currency currency_;
    Tax tax_;
    

public:
    Amount(std::string const & description, float brutto, Currency currency, Tax taxtype) :
        description_{description},
        brutto_{brutto}, 
        netto_{0},             
        currency_{currency}, 
        tax_{taxtype} 
    {} 
};
```

Hopefully this makes it clearer.  Also, you should initialize the variables in the same order they are declared (since that's the order they're actually initialized anyway), and also you didn't initialize netto_ so I gave it a 0.  And finally, I passed your string by reference to avoid unnecessary copies.  I removed your constants because they were not part of this issue, and you probably want the conversion rates to be configurable anyway.